# Python version used within the Apache Airflow package in a Docker image

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I'm using the PowerShell from VSCode in W10. To be able to use Airflow in W10 I'm using a docker image. I have "downloaded" an apache/airflow docker image with:

```
(my_env) PS E:\my_project> docker pull apache/airflow
```

Then when I check the Python version used in airflow within the docker image:

```
(my_env) PS E:\my_project> docker run apache/airflow airflow version   
2.6.2
(my_env) PS E:\my_project> docker run apache/airflow python --version
Python 3.7.17
(my_env) PS E:\my_project> python --version
Python 3.11.3
```

So the airflow image is the latest version 2.6.2 (as of June 2023), but that image uses Python 3.7. The virtual environment I'm using uses Python 3.11. Should I use 3.7 in my environment to avoid problems? Or there won't be conflicts at all?

Comment: I check on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/) that airflow supports python 3.7 and higher. Usually you do not need to worry about using old versions of python unless you use features only available in newer version python.

Answer (score 0):

From the `PyPI` page: https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/, the Airflow package requires `Python ~=3.7`. This means it accepts Python versions 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, and 3.11.
So, it's fine, you shouldn't have conflicts with these versions.